# Parent method not called with instantiated child

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

assuming that:

```
class Parent {
  foo = (message) => 'parent and ' + message
}

class Child extends Parent {
  foo = (message = 'child foo') => super.foo(message)
}
```

Why the follow test does not pass?

```
describe('Child', () => {
  it('should call parent foo and return \'parent and child foo\'', () => {
    const child = new Child()
    const expectedResponse = 'parent and child foo'

    const response = child.foo()

    expect(response).toBe(expectedResponse)
  })
})
```

Throws an error: `TypeError: (intermediate value).foo is not a function`

Should not `Parent`s foo exists and be called?

Comment: Just turn `foo` into a standard method rather than an arrow function directly inside the class, if that's an option

Comment: @CertainPerformance, so `super` acts like `this` when inside arrow functions?

Comment: Yep `An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine when you define them as methods. You are running into arrow function context issues

```js
class Parent {
  foo(message){return 'parent and ' + message} 
}

class Child extends Parent {
  foo(message = 'child foo'){return  super.foo(message)}
}
const child = new Child()
console.log(child.foo())
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's best to use method syntax inside of classes. https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/of-classes-and-arrow-functions-a-cautionary-tale/:

"I’ve never felt comfortable using arrow functions as stand-ins for class methods. Methods should be dynamically scoped according to the instance that calls them, but an arrow function is by definition statically scoped."